# Clear cell content based on another cell change in a Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to clear the cell in 'column J' upon the change of the corresponding cell in "column I".

it's only effective when I change the cell value by myself manually but the data is a result of filter and when it changes it doesn't work even though I made a trigger for the script.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "con" ) {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 9 ) { 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      nextCell.setValue("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: inEdit triggers are only generated on user edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the code like this if you use the event object:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "con" && e.range.columnStart == 9) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue("");
  }
}
```